# CSS3 effects on Android Browser

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cross-browser, web-applications

I have made a set of HTML5 pages using Jquery mobile.  While developing I used Chrome, Safari & ripple emulator to see how my web pages were looking.  I then put my pages on a local server and observed that in iPad & iPhone my pages were getting rendered properly but on Android browser the CSS effects would not work at all.  All my jQuery mobile grids/themes went for a toss.  Why would something like that happen?

I have used the Copy-and-Paste Snippets CDN hosted '.min' files for my stylesheets and javascripts, haven't downloaded them separately.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1,        target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"  /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an incompatibility between the android browser and the CSS you are using. OS version of ur android browser?

Comment: 2.1-2.3 OS, jquery mobile uses CSS3

Comment: **Alright here is the Answer -  Android browser of OS 2.1-2.3 has a very poor support for CSS3 effects, Google has improved its browser performance ICS onwards**